# Limesurvey "Webpage is not available"

Tags: limesurvey

I have created and used many surveys in Limesurvey.  When I tried to log in recently I received the message "Webpage is not available"  None of my surveys that I have created are available.

Comment: This seems to be a browser message meaning that the problem seems to be either a network or server that hosts your LimeSurvey problem. You must provide some more info.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Lime Survey on the Lime Query Site?  If so I believe that if you don't visit the site for a long period of time your account can be culled.  However, I have had good luck contacting Lime Query and getting help whenever issues have come up.  Perhaps they have an archive that they could restore from for you ... as a special favor.

If its your own installation on your server I am not sure what the issue would be.